# Indy TIdTCPClient ConnectTimout not working

Tags: sockets, delphi, tcpclient, indy, connection-timeout

I have a TIdTCPClient which is trying to connect to a host which is not online.

**UPDATE:**
After diving a bit deeper into WINSOCK2 it seems like this is indeed an issue which is depending on your operating system. Maybe there will be a fix in a future release.
(See the comments of this question for more details)

**Setup:**

- Delphi 10 Seattle
- Windows 7 64-Bit
- Indy 10.6.2.5311

The ConnectTimeout is set to 5000 ms so I would expect to get at least a ConnectTimeout after 5 seconds. However on my current machine it takes over 20 seconds to receive that Timeout.

So far I see that the ConnectionTimeout is handled correctly but on *TIdIOHandlerStack.ConnectClient* there is an **WaitFor** on the thread which performs the actual connection attempt. 
I think this is causing the delayed connection timeout, but I don't know what I could do about that. Any Ideas?

**Code:**

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Self.mmo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now));
    Self.idtcpclnt1.Host := '192.148.89.112';
    Self.idtcpclnt1.Port := 9200;
    Self.idtcpclnt1.Connect;
  except on E: Exception do
    Self.mmo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now)+ ' : '+E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.idtcpclnt1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
    const AStatusText: string);
begin
  Self.mmo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now)+ ' : ' +AStatusText);
end;
```

Result of this code:

[image]

Comment: If the connect thread is not terminating in a timely manner, it likely means the previous call to `Close()` is not causing the socket API `connect()` to abort immediately. Although that is not a guarantee on all platforms, I've never seen that happen on Windows. Closing a socket in one thread while another thread is blocked on `connect()` should cause an immediate error. Please diagnose further to determine whether the real problem is actually with the `connect()` not aborting or the thread wait not waking up. Those are two very different issues.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but my impression is, that after calling `Close` the `LThread.WaitFor` needs more than 10seconds to complete. 

I'm talking about line 282 in `TIdIOHandlerStack`:
`TIdIOHandlerStack.ConnectClient.DoConnectTimeout`

Comment: It seems to me that WinSock2 has some kind of minimum blocking time around 20 seconds on my machine. This is causing the connect thread to wait for its call of FBinding.Connect to complete. 

The last thing I can see is that call of `CheckForSocketError(IdWinsock2.connect(ASocket, IdWinsock2.PSOCKADDR(@LAddr), LSize));` in TIdStackWindows which blocks for those strange 20 seconds no matter what somebody wants to do with the connect thread.

Comment: `Close()` calls the Winsock `shutdown()` and `closesocket()` functions, which *should* abort any blocking Winsock function in progress. I find it hard to believe that Winsock's `connect()` function would keep blocking for 20s after closing the socket, but I suppose it is possible. Closing the socket is the only way to abort a blocking socket call, which is why Indy uses a worker thread for the connect. That being said, I have some new code that runs `connect()` in non-blocking mode on Windows so no thread is used and the timeout is better respected, but I have no ETA on that release.

Comment: After digging a bit deeper I have to agree. However I have multiple clients running Windows 7 with this 'issue' and even Windows Server 2012 which are affected in the same way.